# Select, count and inner join same time

Tags: php, select, join, count

I have a table which includes 130k+ rows. I want to list most liked users.

I try lots of queries but I didnt get result.

table 1 : "users" / user_id / user_name
table 2 : "likes" / datetime / user_id

```php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id, b.user_id,b.user_name
   FROM dbo.likes AS a 
   INNER JOIN dbo.users AS b 
   ON a.user_id= b.user_id
) AS subquery;");
```

and

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

echo $row=['user_name'].'-'.$row=['count(*)'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select user_name, count(user_name) 
  from users, likes
  where users.user_id = likes.user_id
  group by user_name
```

Comment: we are counting likes.user_id

Comment: Yeah, your php example script is confusing. Please provide a sample input and output data.